# jquery search for part of a word

Tags: jquery, find, fragment, break, words

I'm getting content from external host through PHP file_get_element and jQuery .load() and inside this content there is a div with some text like this:

"Department of Orthopaedics, Vienna General Hospital and the University of Vienna, Austria."
or 
"Department of Neurosurgery, Donauspital SMZ-Ost, Vienna, Austria."
or
"Department of Traumatology, University of Innsbruck, Anichstrasse 35, A-6020 Innsbruck, Austria. hacklwol@hotmail.com"
or
"Orthopädisches Spital Speising, Vienna, Austria. j.krugluger@innonet.at"

For every .load I make I get a diferent text, and what i need to do is save in my database the departments, but the problem is the different languages (Orthopedic, Orthopädisches, Orthopaedics, etc).

In all the cases I can find "Ortho" or "Neuro", or "Trauma", so I've tried something like this:

```
    if($(".afflist:contains('Ortho')")){ ortho = 1; }
    if($(".afflist:contains('Neuro')")){ neuro = 1; }
```

Please, someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery(selector)` will return a [jQuery Object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) which will be truthy always, you need to check whether the number of elements returned by the selector is greater than 0 like

```
if ($(".afflist:contains('Ortho')").length) {
    ortho = 1;
}
if ($(".afflist:contains('Neuro')").length) {
    neuro = 1;
}
```